# How to output the amount of documents per author in a directory

Tags: bash, files, search

I am trying to count a set of documents from a text dataset by author. I have a directory of books which are named by the author followed by the title. I want to output the number of documents in the directory for each author. An example of some files can be seen here for the ls command:

```
'Winston Churchill___Richard Carvel, Complete.txt'
'Winston Churchill___The Celebrity, Complete.txt'
'Winston Churchill___The Crisis, Complete.txt'
'Winston Churchill___The Crossing.txt'
'Winston Churchill___The Dwelling Place of Light, Complete.txt'
'Winston Churchill___The Inside of the Cup, Complete.txt'
'Zane Grey___Betty Zane.txt'
'Zane Grey___Desert Gold.txt'
'Zane Grey___Riders of the Purple Sage.txt'
'Zane Grey___Tales of Fishes.txt'
'Zane Grey___Tales of lonely trails.txt'
'Zane Grey___The Border Legion.txt'
'Zane Grey___The Call of the Canyon.txt'
'Zane Grey___The Day of the Beast.txt'
'Zane Grey___The Desert of Wheat.txt'
```

I can't count them manually as there are over 3000 documents.

Comment: Do they all have three underscores for separating autor and title: `author___title`?

Comment: @Fiximan Yes they do.

Comment: Are the single quotes part of the filenames?

Comment: @Kusalananda No they are not. in a regular file viewer GUI there are no quotes. It's just that there are spaces in the name so it shows it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick (assuming `.txt`-suffix, no subfolders and '___' as author separator):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n' | awk -F'___' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

On different lines for readability:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n' |
  awk -F'___' '{print $1}' |
  sort |
  uniq -c
```

What it does:

- use `find` to list all files with:

  a)`.txt`-suffix (`-name '*.txt'`)

  b) in the current directory, not in subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`)

  c) without listing the dir itself (`-mindepth 1`)

  d) print the filename without leading directory name and a newline in the end `-printf '%f\n'`
- use `awk`

  ```
  a) define three underscores as field separator `-F'___'`

  b) print first field (author) only `'{print $1}'`
  ```
- `sort` the output just to be sure
- use `uniq` to list unique entries only and `-c`ount them

---

Of course if you have things like newlines in your filenames, you will have to resort to zero-terminated listings. So for extra prudent processing:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.txt'  -printf '%f\000' | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\x00" ; FS="___" ; ORS=\x00"} {print $1}' | sort -z | uniq -zc | tr '\000' '\n'
```

However, I consider this overkill here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the first command you gave me returns "find: paths must precede expression: `printf'"

Comment: Ah don't worry, you just forgot the '-' before printf in your solution. It works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ for name in *___*.txt; do printf '%s\n' "${name%%__*}"; done | uniq -c
   6 Winston Churchill
   9 Zane Grey
```

This simply prints the author names to `uniq -c` which counts the occurrences of each name.  The name is had from each filename by deleting everything from the first occurrence of `___` (triple underscore) in the filename.

Sorting the output of the loop before calling `uniq -c` is not needed as the result of a filename globbing expansion is always sorted (lexicographically).

This assumes that no author's name contains newline characters. Newlines are allowed after the triple underscore though.